# Is "running" a gerund here?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech

In this following sentence:

> The boy is running?

Is the word "running" a gerund? If so, why does this make sense? Why does the sentence structurally make sense?

Answer (score 2):

[On English Language & Usage, nohat wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70/28567):

> A gerund is a form of a verb used as a noun, whereas a participle is a form of verb used as an adjective or as a verb in conjunction with an auxiliary verb.
>
> In English, the present participle has the same form as the gerund, and the difference is in how they are used.

In the case of your question, **is** is an auxiliary verb and **running** is a present participle.

Answer (score 2):

> The boy is running.

The sentence is in the present continuous, in which the word running has been used as a present participle, not as a gerund.

The word running as a gerund means the action of running. You can say "The boy likes running", "Running is his hobby", but you cannot call  a person running. In other words,  It's nonsensical to say "The boy is the activity or action of running".